# Escaping a forwardslash in a text string regex python

Tags: python, regex

Trying to obtain the numerical value and it appears the forward slash along with the second word boundary if giving me some problems.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is coming from a text file and it should return about a hundred or so values into a list so it needs to be dynamic

```
#Here is the text of interest, I am trying to obtain just the numerical value of 268
Average Price/Square Foot\n$268

#I've tried these different methods for escaping the backslash but they are not working
avg_sqft_price = re.findall(r'\bAverage Price\W/\bSquare Foot\n$268\n\$(d\*)',data)
avg_sqft_price = re.findall(r'\bAverage Price[\b]/\bSquare Foot\n$268\n\$(d\*)',data)
avg_sqft_price = re.findall(r'\bAverage Price\B/\bSquare Foot\n$268\n\$(d\*)',data)
avg_sqft_price = re.findall(r'\bAverage Price\/\bSquare Foot\n$268\n\$(d\*)',data)
```

Answer (score 2):

The forward `/` is just a forward `/`, it has no specific meaning to `re` and there's nothing to escape. The issue is that you're trying to match things twice over:

```
\bAverage Price\W/\bSquare Foot\n$268\n\$(d\*)
```

`\W` is already going to match `/`, so you're trying to match it twice, then you're matching `$268` however unlike `/`, `$` *is* a regex metacharacter (matches an end of string / end of line) so you *do* need to escape it, then you're trying to match  *again* except instead of \$\d+ you're matching a literal $ (this one's good), a literal d and a literal `*`. Since the latter is repeated in *all* your attempts nothing can ever work no matter what mess you make of earlier bits.

Also all your `\b` are pretty much useless though they're at least harmless. Which the `\B` is not since you're trying to match a non-word-boundary right at very explicit word boundary.

`Average Price/Square Foot\n\$(\d+)` seems to be what you're looking for: https://regex101.com/r/NyuTh7/2

Answer (score 0):

Forward slash is not a regex metacharacter, and therefore does not require any special handling.  I would use this approach:

```
inp = "Average Price/Square Foot\n$268"
num = re.findall(r'\bAverage Price/Square Foot\s*?\$(\d+)\b', inp)[0]
print(num)
```

This prints `268`.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is coming from a text file and it should return about a hundred or so values into a list so it needs to be dynamic @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Is DOTALL flag necessary here? It has no effect on `\s` at all

Comment: @bryan -- the `re.findall()` operation will return matches into a list that you can iterate across.